# Getting error - Failed: Cannot read property 'click' of null

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

Hi I am working on angular2. I am writing unit test case for delete operation. In real time I am making API call to delete user. To unit test i have created json objecr array and I am making required operations. Below is my code for delete operation.

```
 it('should', async(() => {
        spyOn(component, 'deleteUser');
        let button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('deleteUser');
        button.click();
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            expect(component.deleteUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
        })
        alert(1);
    }));
```

Below is my service.

```
  deleteUserEndpoint(userid: string) {
        var deleteUserUserOnboard = { result: true };
        return Observable.of(deleteUserUserOnboard);
    }
```

Below is my html code.

```
 <a class="btn btn-link btn-xs" href="javascript:;" id="deleteUser" (click)="deleteUser(row)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{'users.management.Delete' | translate}}</a>
```

I have below error.

```
Failed: Cannot read property 'click' of null
```

I am newbie to unit testing. Can someone tell me what would be the expected behavior? Also may I know am I doing something wrong here? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not able to get `button` object in  `button.click()` , as per your error text.
I think providing `deleteUser` button's `ID` (`#deleteUser` instead of `deleteUser`) would help you get it.

```
fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#deleteUser')
```

Comment: Thank you. After adding # in the beginning error fixed. But i am started to get Expected spy on deleteUser to be 'true'. this error. May I know what would be I am missing here?

Comment: not getting it. Could you please rephrase? what's there in `deleteUser` function?

Comment: After expect i have added expect(component.deleteUser).toBe('true');. I removed it now. It is working fine now.